# Running 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 1545 having random system lockups

Tags: 12.04, system, lock

I just reinstalled a fresh 12.04 because I couldn't even get booted on my previous installation anymore.

I just installed 8GB of ram on this laptop, but the problem happened even before this, and all I have installed in this run on Ubuntu is:
 ia32libs, 
Oracle JDK7 and the 32bit JRE 
 junipernc 
jupiter

The laptop has never been used very heavily, so could someone get back to me on this, let me know what further information you need about my machine, or files to upload. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps I do see this entry when i grep 'fail' in my kern.log: [drm] MTRR allocation failed.  Graphics performance may suffer. and: init: failsafe main process (791) killed by TERM signal

Answer (score 0):

Check if your random system lookups happen during file operations,
if they do you might try using another scheduler for example :
    echo "deadline" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler

If it does [here](http://techtitbits.com/2010/04/get-rid-of-freeze-ups-during-disk-io-activity-in-ubuntu/) you can find out how to make it permanent.

Comment: If you could summarize the important information on that page in your own words your answer (by editing your answer), while continuing to provide the link for reference, that would make this answer even better.